# How to Compile APK with Folders in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

need assistance once again.
I'm not sure how to put it across as a meaningful question, but I'll give it a shot.

I am trying to compile the APK using buildozer. This is how my folder looks like.
[image]

When I execute the command `buildozer -v android debug`, the APK is created but it doesn't run. I suspect that the two folders `kivymd` and `navigationdrawer` were not included in the process.

1. Is there anything that needs to be done in the buildozer.spec file as well ?
2. Is there something which I'm missing here ?

Please assist !

Comment: Don't guess what's wrong, [debug it](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can include those directories by adding to the `source.include_patterns` in your `.spec` file. Something like:

```
source.include_patterns = images/*.png
```

That can be comma separated list of patterns. You shouldn't need to list anything that is mentioned in an `import` statement.

Comment: Hi John,I tried that you mentioned and added the names of the folders kivymd,navigationdrawer in the source.include_patterns

source.include_patterns=kivymd/*.*,navigationdrawer/*.*

the apk compiled still doesn't work on the phone. It closes the moment I try to open it

Answer (score 0):

Buildozer includes everything in the local directory and below, if it matches the rules in the buildozer.spec

In particular the file extensions

Hope you get it.